# R: X-axis value is outside the figure in a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

This code for a bar chart works fine, but it has one flaw, and I don't know what it is. The figure it produces does not show completely. As you can see, in the x-axis the last number "100" is almost completely outside the figure. How to fix this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- mydata %>%
  mutate(
    variable = recode(
      variable,
      "item3" = "item name here"
    )
  ) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(value = recode(value, "1" = "yes", "2" = "no", "3" = "maybe")) %>%
  count(variable, value) |> 
  group_by(variable) |> 
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n))

ggplot(mydata, mapping = aes(x = value, y = pct)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = value),
           width = 0.30
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.2),
    minor_breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.1),
    labels = seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 20),
    limits = c(0, 1),
    expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(yes = "green", no = "red", maybe = "grey80"
               ),
    drop = FALSE
  ) +
  labs(x = "Answer", y = "Percentage") +
  guides(
    fill = "none"
  ) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "lightgrey"),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour = "grey"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      size = 11,
      face = "bold",
      hjust = 0
    )
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: You could make some space for the label by increasing the `plot.margin` on the right, e.g. `theme(plot.margin = margin(t = 5.5, r =  11, b = 5.5, l = 5.5))`

Comment: It's from setting `expand=c(0,0)` in `scale_y_continuous()`.  It needs space for the rest of the number, but you're not giving it any.